# Update an element of an Array in a Document in MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB database whith a collection with this structure:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b670eefe94672265ca59428"),
    "duration" : {
        "start" : ISODate("2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "end" : ISODate("2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    },
    "title" : "Example title.",
    "description" : "<p>Hi example!</p>",
    "slug" : "title",
    "insertDate" : ISODate("2018-08-05T14:51:27.194Z"),
    "webData" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bb1f082931c536950ade361"),
            "webCode" : "be_mx",
            "categories" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("3sdf43f34543et35tret435"),
                    "name" : "Category 1",
                    "webCode" : "be_mx",
                    "slug" : "category-1"
                },{
                    "_id" : ObjectId("3sdf43f34543et35tretert"),
                    "name" : "Category 2",
                    "webCode" : "be_mx",
                    "slug" : "category-2"
                }
            ]            
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 6,
    "lastEditionDate" : ISODate("2018-10-01T10:01:38.889Z")    
}
```

I want to update all documents from this collection that has a categorie with a _id = "3sdf43f34543et35tret435" (in this example the "Category 1"), and I want to update this element category setting, for example, the slug to "category-3".

I tried to do that with this code:

```
Collection.update({
            "webData.categories": {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        _id: ObjectId("3sdf43f34543et35tret435")
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $set: {
                    webData: {
                        "categories.$.slug": "category-3"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                multi: true
            }, (err, res) => {
                if (err) { console.log(err); }
                console.log(res);
            });
```

When I execute that, all the documents that have this category are edited but it's wrong because all the related categories are deleted.

Can you help me with this operation?

Thank you!

**EDITED:**

When I execute in my DB this query:

```
db.getCollection("scholarships").update({}, 
{ '$set': { 'webData.[].categories.$[category].slug': "nana" } }, 
{ multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'category._id': ObjectId("5b719d821f3f1131ec4524f6") }] })
```

Using in this time an arrayFilter, I receive this error:

*The path 'webData.[].categories' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates."*

Comment: Use arrayFilters. Something like `Collection.update({}, { '$set': { 'webData.[].categories.$[category].slug': "category-3"} }, { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'category._id': ObjectId("3sdf43f34543et35tret435") }] }`

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'm trying to do that but nothing occours. I never used arrayFilters, sorry! Can you tell me what I must to put inside **$[category]**?

Comment: category is a placeholder which gets resolved from array filters. What is ObjectId ? Is that a mongoose type ? Can you show me the query after you made the above change ? What is your mongoose and mongo server version ?

Comment: `Scholarship.update({}, { '$set': { 'webData.[].categories.$[category].slug': body.slug } }, { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'category._id': id }] })` 
Really I filter by id with a string variable. This is the exact code.

Comment: Query looks good. Please verify you are using mongo server 3.6 version. You have to use ObjectId(stringid).

Comment: This is my MongoDB server version: 4.0.2, thank you, I will investigate more...

Comment: Sure. You can use `mongoose.set("debug", true)` to see the query that is sent over to mongo.

Comment: Uhmm.. when I add this debug code I can see all queries sent over to mongo but exactly this update query didn't appear.

Comment: When I try to execute this query in my database:
`db.getCollection("scholarships").update({}, 
{ '$set': { 'webData.[].categories.$[category].slug': "nana" } }, 
{ multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'category._id': ObjectId("5b719d821f3f1131ec4524f6") }] })`
I receive this error:
**The path 'webData.[].categories' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates."**

Comment: My apologies it should be `$[]`. Please try `db.getCollection("scholarships").update({}, { '$set': { 'webData.$[].categories.$[category].slug': "nana" } }, { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'category._id': ObjectId("5b719d821f3f1131ec4524f6") }] })`

Comment: No, I'm sorry, now I receive this error: **Cannot apply array updates to non-array element webData: null**

Comment: It appears you have some documents without webData field. Use the query filter to limit the document to one has the matching category id. Something like `db.getCollection("scholarships").update({"webData.categories._id":ObjectId("5b719d821f3f1131ec4524f6") }, { '$set': { 'webData.$[].categories.$[category].slug': "nana" } }, { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{ 'category._id': ObjectId("5b719d821f3f1131ec4524f6") }]} );`

Comment: Yes, it is! Now works perfectly! Thank you very much @Veeram :)